# Importing a css file in bootstrap react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Importing a css file in bootstrap react.

For navigation, an additional header.css file will be used.
In bootstrap without react I embed the file as follows:

```
<Nav class="navbar-abc-header navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

In bootstrap react this entry does not work.

```
        render ( ) {
            return (
                <Navbar navbar-abc-header fixedTop>
        ...
        );
    }

I can use <Navbar inverse fixedTop> but not my own css file.
```

As we the css file included right?

Comment: IIRC, reactjs uses className="classesgoeshere"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use className in reactjs. class in a reserved keyword javascript hence you cannot use the same for defining CSS classes.

```
<Nav className="navbar-abc-header navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```